Wrapping issues with wxPython
I am building an app using wxPython but I am having trouble with the text wrapping on the StaticText elements. The wrapping is working for other elements without using Wrap().
With this test, you should be able to see that any of the extended values in the list are not being wrapped properly, and instead cut off.
import wx
import wx.lib.agw.aui as aui
import wx.html

def test():
    pass
    
def text(parent, txt):
    text_element = wx.StaticText(parent, label=txt)
    return text_element

def box(parent='', static=False, label='', direction=wx.HORIZONTAL):
    orient = direction
    text = label if label else ''

    if static:
        # Create a static box and static box sizer if the static parameter is True
        static_box = wx.StaticBox(parent,size=-1, label=text)
        box_sizer = wx.StaticBoxSizer(static_box, orient)
    else:
        # Create a regular box sizer if the static parameter is False
        box_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(orient)

    return box_sizer

def list(parent, linked_items=None, regular_items=None):
    if not linked_items and not regular_items:
        raise ValueError("Linked list items AND regular list items cannot be None")
    
    vbox = box(direction=wx.VERTICAL)
    
    item_list = []
    number = 1
    for item_l in linked_items:
        hbox = box()
        left_label = text(parent, f"{number}.")
        item_list.append(left_label)
        hbox.Add(left_label, flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL | wx.ALIGN_LEFT | wx.ALL, border=5)
        
        print(len(item_l[0])*14)
        html = wx.html.HtmlWindow(parent, size=(len(item_l[0])*8, 40),style=wx.html.HW_SCROLLBAR_NEVER)
        html.SetPage(f'<span style="color: #FF0000" ><a href="{item_l[0]}">{item_l[0]}</a></span>')
        html.Bind(wx.html.EVT_HTML_LINK_CLICKED, item_l[1])
        item_list.append(html)
        hbox.Add(html, proportion=1, flag=wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL)
        
        
        right_label = text(parent, f"{item_l[2]}")
        item_list.append(right_label)
        hbox.Add(right_label, proportion= 1, flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL | wx.ALIGN_LEFT | wx.RIGHT | wx.TOP | wx.BOTTOM, border = 5)
        vbox.Add(hbox,proportion=0,flag=wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL)
        
        number += 1
    for item_r in regular_items:
        label = text(parent, f"{number}. {item_r}")
        item_list.append(label)
        vbox.Add(label, proportion= 0, flag= wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, border=5)
        number += 1
    
    vbox.Layout()
    
    return vbox, item_list

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App
    frame = wx.Frame(None, title='title', size = (1024,768))
    _mgr = aui.AuiManager(frame)
    panel = wx.Panel(frame)
    
    main_sizer = box()
    side_center = box()
    center_sizer = box(direction=wx.VERTICAL)
    
    linked_list = [
        ['Create a New Project',test, ': rquoipktdvohixqzvogkplqheturogclr gpzpvqujlyxrrcbolmyjfjruojkudsodfevgbxypnnoalvhyxsdirmbrnss.'],
        ['Open an Existing Project',test, ': Pick up the call where you left off.'],
        ['Explore TestValue Cases',test, ': rquoipktdvohixqzvogkplqheturogclr gpzpvqujlyxrrcbolmyjfjruojkudsodfevgbxypnnoalvhyxsdirmbrnss.'],
    ]
    regular_list = [
        'rquoipktdvohixqzvogkplqheturogclr gpzpvqujlyxrrcbolmyjfjruojkudsodfevgbxypnnoalvhyxsdirmbrnss.',
        'rquoipktdvohixqzvogkplqheturogclr gpzpvqujlyxrrcbolmyjfjruojkudsodfevgbxypnnoalvhyxsdirmbrnss.'
    ]

    list_size, list_items = list(panel, linked_list, regular_list)

    center_sizer.Add(list, proportion=1, flag=wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, border=5)
        
    side_center.Add(center_sizer, flag= wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL | wx.TOP | wx.BOTTOM, border=100)
        
    main_sizer.Add(side_center,flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL | wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL | wx.RIGHT | wx.LEFT, border=200)

    panel.SetSizer(main_sizer)
    panel.Layout()
    panel.Refresh()

    _mgr.AddPane(panel, aui.AuiPaneInfo().Name('panel').CenterPane())
    _mgr.Update()

Is there any way to avoid this? Or should I give up on the Python-based UI? I'm only using wxPython since it was easy to implement a large application before a deadline. I can switch it to something else (If that is the case, leave a suggestion in the comment/answer).

The key is to ensure that the proportion for elements added to sizers is correct for intended purposes.
The wrapping errors were fixed by changing:
# ...
    right_label = text(parent, f"{item_l[2]}")
    item_list.append(right_label)
    hbox.Add(right_label, proportion= 1, flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL | wx.ALIGN_LEFT | wx.RIGHT | wx.TOP | wx.BOTTOM, border = 5)
    vbox.Add(hbox,proportion=0,flag=wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL)
        
    number += 1
for item_r in regular_items:
    label = text(parent, f"{number}. {item_r}")
    item_list.append(label)
    vbox.Add(label, proportion= 0, flag= wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, border=5)
# ...

to
# ...
    hbox_right = box()
    right_label = text(parent, f"{item_l[2]}")
    item_list.append(right_label)
    hbox_right.Add(right_label, proportion=0, flag=wx.EXPAND)
        
    hbox.Add(hbox_right, proportion=1, flag=wx.EXPAND)
    vbox.Add(hbox, proportion=1, flag=wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL)
        
    number += 1
for item_r in regular_items:
    label = text(parent, f"{number}. {item_r}")
    item_list.append(label)
    vbox.Add(label, proportion= 1, flag= wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, border=5)
    number += 1
# ...

It is not pretty, as the smaller text will appear to the right of the screen, but this does solve the inherent issue that was being asked.
